# How do I run multiple testcases defined in different classes with two different logins using Selenium,Java and TestNG?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Example:

```
Public class A()
{
Method A1
Method A2
}

Public class B()
{
Method B1
Method B2
}
```

I am using dataprovider to get the login info (id and password) from excel

```
Public class login()  
{
User1
User2
}
```

I want to run all methods of both classes for both Users.The login info (user id, password) come from the external source (excel)

```
User1:
Method A1
Method A2
Method B1
Method B2

User2:
Method A1
Method A2
Method B1
Method B2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange. What all have you tried from your end till now. What is the error that you are getting. Also go through [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is complete workaround to your problem.**

Create class `ClassA`...

```
public class ClassA {
    public void methodA1() {
        System.out.println("methodA1");
    }
    public void methodA2() {
        System.out.println("methodA2");
    }
}
```

Create class `ClassB`...

```
public class ClassB {
    public void methodB1() {
        System.out.println("methodB1");
    }
    public void methodB2() {
        System.out.println("methodB2");
    }
}
```

Create class `ClassC` ..i.e. containing `DataProvider Test`

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassC {

    ClassA methodA = new ClassA();
    ClassB methodB = new ClassB();

        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] dataMethod() {
            Object[][] arrayObjects = getLoginData("C:/logininfo.xlsx");
            return arrayObjects;    
        }

        @Test(dataProvider = "dataMethod")
        public void testMethod(String email, String password) throws InterruptedException {
            methodA.methodA1();
            methodA.methodA2();
            methodB.methodB1();
            methodB.methodB2();

        }

        public String[][] getLoginData(String fileName){
            String[][] arrayLoginData = null;
            return arrayLoginData;
        }
}
```

Create `loginTest.xml` file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Multiple Test" verbose="10">

  <test name="LoginTest" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="ClassC" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Make changes as per your need.